# SQL - Auctions - List multiple highest bids

Tags: database, postgresql, greatest-n-per-group

My Auctions

```
CREATE TABLE Auction (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  owner_id INTEGER REFERENCES Registered(user_id),
  title VARCHAR(50) NOT NULL,
  starting_bid NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL CHECK (starting_bid >= 0),
  starting_time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  ending_time TIMESTAMP NULL CHECK (starting_time < ending_time),
  status_id INTEGER REFERENCES AuctionStatus(id),
  winner_id INTEGER REFERENCES Registered(user_id) NULL,
  highest_bid NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL
);
```

My Bids

```
CREATE TABLE Bid (
  id SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id INTEGER REFERENCES Registered(user_id),
  auction_id INTEGER REFERENCES Auction(id),
  bid_value NUMERIC(10,2) CHECK (VALUE > 0),
  creation_date TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
  valid BOOLEAN DEFAULT TRUE NOT NULL
);
```

I want a user to be able to list all the auctions where he has bid + his highest bid in each auction.

I started with

```
SELECT auction.id, auction.title, auction.highest_bid, bid.bid_value
FROM auction
JOIN bid
ON auction.id = bid.auction_id
WHERE bid.owner_id = :userID AND bid.active = TRUE AND auction.status_id = 1
```

to list all of his bids but I'm having trouble moving forward from here to get the highest bid of the user for each auction.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT distinct on (auction.id) auction.id, auction.title, auction.highest_bid, bid.bid_value
FROM auction
JOIN bid
ON auction.id = bid.auction_id
WHERE bid.owner_id = :userID AND bid.active = TRUE AND auction.status_id = 1
ORDER BY auction.id, bid.bid_value desc;
```

For more info see:

[Select first row in each GROUP BY group?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3800551/select-first-row-in-each-group-by-group)

and

"DISTINCT Clause" paragraph from
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html

Comment: I see. I remembered DISTINCT, but I forgot the ORDER BY.